# Exporting data from Neo4j to Gephi is not showing all nodes

Tags: neo4j, graphql, cypher, gephi

I am facing a real problem with extracting data (nodes and relations) from neo4j to gephi. I am using using the apoc.gephi.add method to do that. This method is only extracting a random subset of the nodes and relations in the neo4j query!

Below you can find the cypher query to extract from neo4j to gephi:

```
  match (t1:tag)<-[:has]- (vid1:video)-[:recommends]->(vid2:video)-[:has]->(t2:tag)
where (t1.title contains 'ukraine' or t1.title contains 'russia') and not (t2.title contains 'ukraine' or t2.title contains 'russia') 
match (u1:user)-[:author]->(vid1)
match path = (u2:user)-[:author]->(vid2)
where u2.verified = 0 and size(u2.nickname) < 4  and u2.commerceUserInfo_commerceUser =1
CALL apoc.gephi.add(null,'workspace1',path,'weight',['title', 'diggCount','followerCount','followingCount','commentCount','heartCount','playCount','shareCount','videoQuality','uniqueId','verified']) yield nodes, relationships, time
return *
```

Neo4j shows 300 nodes and there relations out of 6100 nodes resulted from this query as shown below:

[Neo4j Resluts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PEwn.png)

However, gephi shows only 61 nodes and 32 relations!

[Gephi Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5avGA.png)

Why is this happening and how to export all nodes from neo4j to gephi?
Thank you

Comment: Hi Ali. I feel that you may have incorrectly tagged this as "graphql". I don't see the relation between GraphQL (as in the API query language) and this question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure it's not a `apoc.gephi.add` problem, but only a wrong query.

I mean, you executed a multiple `match` but in your `apoc.gephi.add` you pass only the `path` variable, that is only the `(u2:user)-[:author]->(vid2)` part,
instead in your final return you do `return *`,
so you return all variables from the other `match`es as well.

If you execute a `return path` instead of `return *`, you should see only the same results as the Gephi attached image.

So i guess you should change it, in order to pass everything you need in your gephi procedure.

I think something like that (but it depends on your dataset anyway):

```
match p1 = (t1:tag)<-[:has]-(vid1:video)-[:recommends]->(vid2:video)-[:has]->(t2:tag)
where (t1.title contains 'ukraine' or t1.title contains 'russia') and not (t2.title contains 'ukraine' or t2.title contains 'russia') 
match p2=(u1)-[:author]->(vid1)
match p3=(u2)-[:author]->(vid2)
where u2.verified = 0 and size(u2.nickname) < 4  and u2.commerceUserInfo_commerceUser =1
with [p1, p2, p3] as dataToAdd
CALL apoc.gephi.add(null,'workspace1', dataToAdd,'weight',['title', 'diggCount','followerCount','followingCount','commentCount','heartCount','playCount','shareCount','videoQuality','uniqueId','verified']) yield nodes, relationships, time
return dataToAdd, nodes, relationships, time
```